# Best Books for Moderate Level Classical Latin

Tags: soft-question, book

I recently completed Duolingo’s Latin course, and now I want to learn classical Latin more in depth. Could you guys please suggest me some good books or free courses? I wouldn’t consider myself a beginner, because I understand basic declensions and cases and the like. *Gratias ago tibi in antecessum!*

Comment: Lots of good recommendations in [this previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8956) (I would especially recommend [Ad Alpes](https://latinitium.com/ad-alpes/) in your situation, for which a complete audio book read by Daniel Petterson is also available).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi MathandPhysics. I'm going to close this as it does seem to be essentially a duplicate of that other thread. I do want to issue a note of caution, though. I did not find that Duolingo gets even close what you're taught in fundamental Latin in school. You might actually benefit from a more traditional beginner's text, and just breezing through the first few chapters. And vocabulary will be important, too, for the reading of advanced texts.

Comment: I recommend also looking at our question on [self-learning](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/957/how-can-i-study-latin-on-my-own) for additional resources and grammars.