# Reading books once you have finished "Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Colloquia Personarum"

Tags: lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, resource-request

Which books can I use to progress in Latin reading once I have finished *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Colloquia Personarum*? The degree of difficulty should correspond more or less to the level you have once you have reached chapter XX of *Lingua latina per se illustrata*.

I've seen this [other question asking for reading resources](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/8956/) and I've read its answers, but there they are asking
for Latin texts to continue reading after highschool, that is, for a higher level than the one I'm asking for. It may be that some of the resources contained in its answers are appropriate for my level, the problem is that it is impossible for me to know this. So, I would like to receive an answer which specifically address the level I've specified: not an absolute beginner, nor an intermediate level, but something in   between. In addition, some of the links in the websites linked in the answers to the above linked question doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Charo, I think the above linked question suffices as an answer also to your question. If you don't think so, let us know why not. We technically have a formal process to go through for resource requests.

Comment: @cmw:  I've seen this question and its answers, but the level of knowledge of Latin I'm asking it's not the same. In addition, some of the links in the websites linked in its answers doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain why? The more details you have, the better. Resource requests typically go through [this meta thread](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188/request-for-most-needed-resource-questions), since otherwise opinion answers are off-topic on StackExchange.

Comment: OK, @cmw: I've edited my question.

Comment: I've kicked it to the other moderators to weigh in. It still feels niche and opinion-based to me, but let's see what others say.

Comment: @Charo This question seems to ask for a long list of recommendations, as there is no unique answer. For list questions like this, the procedure is to propose it in the meta question cmw linked to. In it's current form the question can be reopened by users voting to reopen but the moderators will probably not vote either way. // Also, I recommend being flexible with your material. Now that you've advanced a bit, you should try different things, like grammars and original texts and stuff that may turn out a little too challenging. I wouldn't keep it too rigid.